# Añadir la etiqueta "localismo"

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad

Deberíamos reemplazar la etiqueta con la frase [diferencias-regionales](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diferencias-regionales) por el término único que la define?

### Localismo

> 4. m. Vocablo o locución que solo tiene uso en un área restringida.

<sub>*[RAE](https://dle.rae.es/localismo)*</sub>

Comment: Para añadir etiquetas, necesita solo [150 reputación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). O es esta pregunta para colecionar las opiniónes de la comunidad?

Comment: Maybe to get some feedback. But I can't find how to add a tag without asking a question and inserting it.

Comment: Busca una pregunta que la necesite y añádesela. Nótese que tenemos [tag:diferencias-regionales], así como una etiqueta por país, etc. En general, es recomendable ver qué etiquetas hay antes de crear una nueva, para intentar que su uso sea lo más estándar posible

Comment: No sabía de la etiqueta "diferencias-regionales". Modifiqué el enunciado de la pregunta, no el título.

Answer (score 1):

"**Regionalismo**" parece tener el [mismo significado](https://dle.rae.es/regionalismo?m=form) (y he aprendido un nuevo significado de la palabra *giro*):

> 3. m. Vocablo o giro privativo de una región determinada.

"Regionalismo" parece ser [más usado](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=regionalismo%2C%20localismo&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=32&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cregionalismo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clocalismo%3B%2Cc0) que "localismo", y [regionalismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regionalismo) es ya un sinónimo de la etiqueta [diferencias-regionales](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diferencias-regionales). La pregunta es si queremos usar el término preciso "regionalismo" o el sintagma (¿quizá más fácil de entender?) "diferencias regionales". No tengo una opinión fuerte al respecto, así que sugeriría hacer el cambio solo si hay cierto apoyo de la comunidad.

Comment: Personalmente interpreto "diferencias regionales" como diferencias dentro de una misma región, por ejemplo entre El Escorial y Madrid centro, que están solo a 100 km. "Regionalismo" lo veo más global: Mexico DF y Buenos Aires.